# Can I access and modify comments using any present Youtube API?

Tags: youtube, google-api

I am working on a project which requires accessing an YouTube account. I am a starter and I have never used an API, so reading/understanding a manual is not so easy for me.

Basically,

> I want to access\remove a comment from videos of a particular channel. So is, there any API available to do that?

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There is an entire developer area dedicated to documenting the YouTube API. Have you spent time looking there? Note: Tutorial/API/reference material recommendation questions are off-topic for StackOverflow. Also note: a web search of "`YouTube API remove comment`" pops up specific documentation to this problem.

Comment: Yeah I saw Youtube API remove comment. Thanks a lot for this. And I didn't knew this question is off topic for StackOverflow

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the official documentation:[Youtube API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/delete)

As far as I know,if you want to delete a comment you'll have to set up a few things before like:authentification.If you look at the javascript example,above the code you'll see a slider.If you drag it to the right,you'll see the whole process.

Comment: I already mentioned this in a comment. And telling someone to use the API is not an answer; it's just... a comment.